# How to manage infiniteScroll with ion-segment

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am using the latest `ionic 3.6.0`.

I am having a problem with `infiniteScroll` and `ion-segment` when one of the segments reaching the end , where `infiniteScroll.enable(false)`. Switching to another segment then, the infiniteScroll is not enabled at all… even if I put the boolean value in a variable and initialize it at constructor level.

.ts:

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll){
   if (this.segment === 'all'){
     this.doInfiniteForSegmentAll(infiniteScroll);
   } else
   if (this.segment === 'featured'){
     this.doInfiniteForSegmentFeatured(infiniteScroll);
   }
 }

doInfiniteForSegmentAll(infiniteScroll){
    this.service.getAllData().subscribe(res => {
       if (res.length > 0){
         //Do stuff
       } else {
         infiniteScroll.enable(false)
         //show a toast
      }
  });
 }

doInfiniteForSegmentFeatured(infiniteScroll){
     this.service.getFeaturedData().subscribe(res => {
       if (res.length > 0){
         //Do stuff
       } else {
         infiniteScroll.enable(false)
         //show a toast
      }
    });
  }
```

.html:

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="segment === 'all' || segment === 'featured'" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" threshold="50px">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingText="Loading" loadingSpinner="dots"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I think it seems that `ion-infinite-scroll` should be separate for each segment.. therefore:

.html:

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="segment === 'all'" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" threshold="50px">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingText="Loading" loadingSpinner="dots"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>

 <ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="segment === 'featured'" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" threshold="50px">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingText="Loading" loadingSpinner="dots"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

This is since I am not using `ngSwitch` and having only one kind of looped list for each segment.